# Can't run GOSU queries in scratchpad

Tags: gosu, guidewire

Recently I upgraded my Guidewire studio from version 8 to 9. From that onwards the database Queries are throwing error while running in scratchpad. The same code works fine in version 8. Please find the code and the error below.

CODE

```
var object = gw.api.database.Query.make(Account).select()
print("Count : "+object.Count)
```

ERROR

```
gw.lang.parser.exceptions.ParseResultsException: Gosu Scratchpad.gsp

Errors:

Could not resolve symbol for : Account [line:3 col:41] in
line 2:
line 3: var object = gw.api.database.Query.make(Account).select()

Expected Type: Type<T>
Line Number: 3  Column: 41

Could not resolve symbol for : Account [line:3 col:41] in
line 2:
line 3: var object = gw.api.database.Query.make(Account).select()

Expected Type: Type<T>
Line Number: 3  Column: 41


    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.ParserBase.verifyParsedElement(ParserBase.java:283)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.ParserBase.verifyParsedElement(ParserBase.java:254)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuClassParser.parseDefinitions(GosuClassParser.java:471)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuClass.compileDefinitionsIfNeeded(GosuClass.java:1539)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuClass.compileDefinitionsIfNeeded(GosuClass.java:1482)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuClass.isValid(GosuClass.java:919)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuProgram_Proxy.isValid(gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuProgram_Proxy:2)
    at gw.internal.gosu.parser.GosuProgramParser.parseExpressionOrProgram(GosuProgramParser.java:190)
    at gw.lang.Gosu.runWithFile(Gosu.java:425)
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your environment aware of your 'Account' type/entity? It looks like it can't parse the name 'Account' any further, and is looking for any generic type.

Comment: I didn't get that. Could u plz elaborate what to do?

Comment: The error makes it sound like the parser doesn't understand what an 'Account' is. Perhaps you're missing a reference to the file where the declaration and definition of 'Account' lives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In v9, you have to install DCEVM to run queries in scratch pad

Comment: Hi Rajesh, what is this dcevm? What does it do? could u plz elaborate..

Comment: are you using v9?

Comment: DCEVM is the Dynamic Code Evolution Module. Basically it modifies your JVM slightly to allow better class reloading on the fly. Have a look at https://dcevm.github.io/

Comment: @AravindRPillai if we made any change in a class in a local environment, DCEVM will reloading the classes, but not Static and sys table changes.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if this works. can you try the below and see it that works.

var object = gw.api.database.Query.make(entity.Account).select()

print("Count : "+object.Count)

Answer (score 1):

V9 Gosu Scratch pad needs DCEVM. This is just a jar, that can be installed.
You will get it form [DCEVM](http://dcevm.github.io/)